# Algorithm return statement does not begin on new line

Tags: line-breaking, algorithmicx

I have the following code for displaying an algorithm:

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Compute index of nearest grid point given particle position (1D)}
  \label{nearestGridPoint}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{FindMeshIndex}{$position$, $nGrid$}
      \State $index=math.floor(position+0.5)+((nGrid/2)+1)$
      \If{$index=-1$}
        \State $index=nGrid-1$
      \EndIf
      \Return $index$
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

The output places the **endif** and **return** statements on the same line. Is there some formatting nuance that I have missed?

Answer (score 36):

```
\State \Return your-text
```

will fix it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is exactly the same as the other answer did.

Comment: I disagree with downvotes. The other answer fails to suggest this simple strategy.

Answer (score 21):

`\Return` doesn't issue a new line in the algorithm. You could force this through a redefinition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\newcommand{\vars}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\func}{\textrm}
\let\oldReturn\Return
\renewcommand{\Return}{\State\oldReturn}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Compute index of nearest grid point given particle position (1D)}
  \label{nearestGridPoint}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{FindMeshIndex}{$\vars{position}, \vars{nGrid}$}
      \State $\vars{index} = \func{math.floor}(\vars{position} + 0.5) + ((\vars{nGrid}/2)+1)$
      \If{$\vars{index} = -1$}
        \State $\vars{index} = \vars{nGrid} - 1$
      \EndIf
      \Return $\vars{index}$
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

`\Return` has been redefined to issue a `\State` *first*.

I've taken the liberty of defining `\vars` (for variables) and `\func` (for functions) which could improve your algorithm display.

Comment: Or, if you only use it once you could simply write "\State\Return" instead of "\Return".

Answer (score 2):

In preamble:

```
\algrenewcommand{\Return}{\State\algorithmicreturn~}
```

Comment: How does this differ from the previous answers?

Comment: The two previous answers say:
1. `\let\oldReturn\Return`; `\renewcommand{\Return}{\State\oldReturn}`
2. `\State \Return your-text`

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution is to add `\\` at the end of the previous `State`.

```
\State bla.. bla.. bla.. \\
\Return bla..
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  This works here.  It would be nice if you could make this into a complete small document and upload a picture of the output too.